# Is using across in these contexts wrong?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, phrase-meaning

> 1. He listens to music of all genres.
>    He listens to music **across** all genres.

> 2. His influence in the world of music is undeniable.
>
>    His influence **across** the world of music is undeniable.

Are the sentences with **across** wrong? How do the sentences with the word **across** differ in meaning from the other ones?

Comment: [***Here's***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=music+%2A+all+genres&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cmusic%20%2A%20all%20genres%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmusic%20of%20all%20genres%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmusic%20in%20all%20genres%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmusic%20from%20all%20genres%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmusic%20across%20all%20genres%3B%2Cc0) the relevant usage chart (for #1) from Google NGrams. As you'll see, "standard" prepositions for your context (most common first) are ***of, in, from, across***. They're all "acceptable" - so you can just choose the one you like best! :)

Comment: You can make your own NGram chart for context #2 by changing the search string i above link to **influence * the world** (resulting link is too long to include in a comment here). The list of prepositions there is ***in, on, around, of, throughout, over, upon, from, through, with*** - which list in fact *doesn't* include ***across***, but it's perfectly okay in your context.

Comment: He listens to all genres of music. No need for across. Across the world of music is the same as across the world.